# JScrollPane Scrolling Horizontally when it Should be Scrolling Vertically

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a panel with FlowLayout specified that is full of labels, text fields, and text areas. The frame isn't that wide, but the panel becomes tall because of all the components inside. I want to add the panel to a JScrollPane, so I can scroll vertically through the panel. However, when I add the panel to the scroll pane and add the scroll pane to the frame, all the components are right next to each other and it scrolls horizontally through them. Here's the code:

```
public class Form {

    JTextField jtfName = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField jtfTitle = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField jtfAuthor = new JTextField(15);

    JTextArea jtaSetting = new JTextArea(5, 15);
    JTextArea jtaMainChars = new JTextArea(5, 15);
    JTextArea jtaConflict = new JTextArea(5, 15);
    JTextArea jtaQuote = new JTextArea(5, 15);
    JTextArea jtaMainCharShows = new JTextArea(5, 15);

    JPanel jpnlName = new JPanel();
    JPanel jpnlTitle = new JPanel();
    JPanel jpnlAuthor = new JPanel();

    Form() {

        // Create a new JFrame container.
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Organizer");

        jfrm.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        // Give the frame an initial size.
        jfrm.setSize(300, 300);

        // Terminate the program when the user closes the application.
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create a panel.
        JPanel jpnl = new JPanel();

        // Create labels.
        JLabel jlabName = new JLabel("Student Name:");
        JLabel jlabTitle = new JLabel("Title:");
        JLabel jlabAuthor = new JLabel("Author:");

        JLabel jlabSetting = new JLabel("Setting (Time and Place):");
        jlabSetting.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);

        JLabel jlabMainChars = new JLabel("Main Characters:");
        jlabMainChars.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);

        JLabel jlabConflict = new JLabel("<html>Describe the major conflict of the<br>story in one well-written sentence:");
        jlabConflict.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);

        JLabel jlabQuote = new JLabel("<html>Find and write down a passage (quote<br>from the book that reveals a significant<br>personality trait of one of the main characters<br>and GIVE THE PAGE #:");
        jlabQuote.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);

        JLabel jlabMainCharShows = new JLabel("<html>Explain in your own words what the<br>passage (quote) shows about the main character.");
        jlabMainCharShows.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);

        // Add text fields to panel.
        jpnlName.add(jlabName);
        jpnlName.add(jtfName);

        jpnlTitle.add(jlabTitle);
        jpnlTitle.add(jtfTitle);

        jpnlAuthor.add(jlabAuthor);
        jpnlAuthor.add(jtfAuthor);

        // Add components to main panel.
        jpnl.add(jpnlName);
        jpnl.add(jpnlTitle);
        jpnl.add(jpnlAuthor);
        jpnl.add(jlabSetting);
        jpnl.add(jtaSetting);
        jpnl.add(jlabMainChars);
        jpnl.add(jtaMainChars);
        jpnl.add(jlabConflict);
        jpnl.add(jtaConflict);
        jpnl.add(jlabQuote);
        jpnl.add(jtaQuote);
        jpnl.add(jlabMainCharShows);
        jpnl.add(jtaMainCharShows);

        // Add the panel to a scroll pane.
        JScrollPane jspPanel = new JScrollPane(jpnl);

        // Add the scroll pane to the frame.
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jspPanel);

        // Display the frame.
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without know exactly the layout you want, the best solution I can suggest is to try the [WrapLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/)

It addresses the major problem with the `FlowLayout`, it doesn't wrap.

Comment: I thought flow layout went to a new line whenever it reached the end of whatever container it's set on.

Comment: No, it doesn't, not if it can help it.  The `ScrollPane` is giving the layout manager the opportunity to "stretch" it's legs if you like.  It's preferred layout is one single, continuous line.  When it can't do that, then it wraps.  The wrap layout will prefer to wrap.  Read the blog entry and you'll see what I'm talking about

Comment: This is more common then you think, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592828/java-scrollpane-with-flowlayout & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575745/borderlayout-nested-center-panel-grows-but-does-not-resize-outer-panel & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909058/why-arent-my-components-wrapping-in-swings-flowlayout and they're just the ones of the top of the list :P

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try BoxLayout:

```
jpnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpnl, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```