# Auto size and Auto Wrap JToolbar

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java swing application that has a **JToolbar** and I'm setting its layout like this:

```
mTools.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

this toolbar has many buttons and is being added to a **JFrame** like this:

```
frame.add(mTools, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

The toolbar is wrapping the buttons as needed (when user changes the with of JFrame), but height of the toolbar is not changing to accommodate for it. And the result likes like this:

---

[image: JToolbar with wrapped buttons]

---

As you can see the top of the buttons in the second row is visible, but the toolbar is not changing the height. How can I force the toolbar to resize the height correctly?
By the way I did try the `mTools.getPreferredSize();`, but the height that it is returning is always the same no matter what.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575745/borderlayout-nested-center-panel-grows-but-does-not-resize-outer-panel/3576061#3576061

Comment: @camickr Thanks, that was the answer